# Not received emails even though the SendGrid activity shows Delivered

Tags: azure-logic-apps, sendgrid

I have created Azure Logic App with Recurrence trigger and then used SendGrid connector for sending emails to multiple team members.

I didn’t receive any email even though the logic app actions executed successfully. After that I have checked SendGrid account email activity status, it is having “**Delivered**” status for the mentioned to email address in the SendGrid action.

Note: I have whitelisted the Outbound IP address of my logic app in SendGrid IP Address Management.

Comment: Is the email in your spam folder? Have you verified your sender through single sender verification or domain authentication?

Comment: No emails in my spam folder. I didn't verify the single sender and domain authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

I don't know how Azure Logic Apps trigger emails with SendGrid, but if an email isn't being sent they shouldn't be getting the "Delivered" status.

You said that you have not set up Single Sender Verification or Domain Authentication. In order to send an email using SendGrid from the email address you provide, that email address should either have been [verified as a Single Sender](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) (which is mostly useful for testing) or it should be from a [domain that you have authenticated with SendGrid](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication).

Try setting one of those verification methods up and then try sending emails again.